# Why implementations for rust debug trait uses Formatter<'_> type elision

Tags: rust

I have this question long ago since from day 1 I started to learn rust. I learned that the implementation for `std::fmt::Debug` has a function signature

`fn fmt(&self, fmt: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result`.

At first I just copy this signature and treat it as a standard boilerplate code. However, as I learned more I realized that `<'_>` means lifetime elision. I did some research and according to [issue #49469](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/48469) `<'_>` can let the return value infer its lifetime according to parameters (which is really cool). But I also see people use `<'_>` extensively with `fmt::Formatter`, such as the [standard library document](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Debug.html) and [mio](https://github.com/tokio-rs/mio/blob/master/src/interest.rs#L111), which in these cases `<'_>` should not change the default lifetime inference behavior. In addition, I did a quick test with the following code

```
use std::fmt;

struct Test();

impl fmt::Debug for Test {
    fn fmt(&self,fmt:&mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        write!(fmt,"test")?;
        Ok(())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let t = Test();
    println!("{:?}",t);
}
```

and it compiles and runs. So does `<'_>` here have some special usages with some edge cases I don't know?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [Rust RFC 2115: Argument Lifetimes](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/2115-argument-lifetimes.md):

> You can write `'_` to explicitly elide a lifetime, and it is deprecated to entirely leave off lifetime arguments for non-`&` types.

And from the included motivation:

> [A] point of confusion for newcomers and old hands alike is the fact that you can leave off lifetime parameters for types:
>
> ```
> struct Iter<'a> { ... }
>
> impl SomeType {
>     // Iter here implicitly takes the lifetime from &self
>     fn iter(&self) -> Iter { ... }
> ```
>
> As detailed in the [ergonomics initiative blog post](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2017/03/02/lang-ergonomics.html), this bit of lifetime elision is considered a mistake: it makes it difficult to see at a glance that borrowing is occurring, especially if you're unfamiliar with the types involved. (The `&` types, by contrast, are universally known to involve borrowing.)

In summary, you should use `fmt::Formatter<'_>`.