# Why define a Formatter with anonymous lifetime?

Tags: rust

I do not know why a `fmt::Formatter` takes anonymous lifetime `<'_>` as shown below.

```
pub struct ParseBoolError {
    _priv: (),
}

impl fmt::Display for ParseBoolError {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> fmt::Result {
        "provided string was not `true` or `false`".fmt(f)
    }
}
```

[Source](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/str/mod.rs.html#15)

I can understand about [anonymous lifetime](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/ownership-and-lifetimes/the-anonymous-lifetime.html).

But, in that case of `ParseBoolError`, I think the anonymous lifetime is not necessary because the `struct ParseBoolError` does not take lifetime.

Comment: [`Formatter<'a>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/struct.Formatter.html) has a lifetime by definition. `<'_>` is there to remind you, that `Formatter`'s lifetime, though can be deduced and elided by the compler, it's still bound by `&self`'s lifetime

Comment: Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63314288/why-implementations-for-rust-debug-trait-uses-formatter-type-elision

Comment: @AlexLarionov: But it would be the lifetime of `self` if it were a return type. AFAIUI, in argument position it simply means a new, unused lifetime.

Comment: Thank you. I understand clearly.